# IT Security Internship

Tags: network

I am a student and working in the field of IT Security for 1 and a half year . I want to know about the best IT security companies for Internships and their general requirements in an intern ?

Comment: Welcome to Security. Please note that you question is out of scope of this site as the answers will be based primarily on opinions. Also we don't give carrer advises here.

Comment: @uwe i just want to know some names . thats all.

Comment: This type of question would be better suited on something like [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/asknetsec).